# MySQL insert country iso or country id from another table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to insert each visitor's country in my database. Maxmind returns the 2 letters country ISO that I could store in a `VARCHAR(2)`, that would use 2 bytes, or, alternatively, I can use an `UNSIGNED TINYINT` that would use 1 byte, and would be the id from a table with all the countries.

However I hit a bump; I need `MyISAM` engine for fast insertions, but MyISAM does not support `FOREIGN KEYS`, so I guess that for each insertion, I will have to make a select in the countries table to retrieve the country id.

I don't know what is the best option, I absolutely need to use `MyISAM` as there will be lots of insertions but I don't want to constantly make `SELECTs` to retrieve the country id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the 2-letter ISO country code (and not the country name, language, or other information) then I'd say that storing it as CHAR(2) with no external table would be less resource-intensive than storing it as SMALLINT (TINYINT wouldn't be enough to cover all countries) with a lookup to an additional table.

Note: there is no need for VARCHAR(2) in this case, CHAR(2) would be more efficient.

Comment: Good idea about the CHAR storage type, I had completely forgotten about it, however an UNSIGNED TINYINT can go up to 255 using only one byte and there are maximum 196 countries.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a associtive array from the country table. Make the country id as the key for this array. Then make it available to your views. So from with in views you can do a lookup against the country array and display the relevent country. for example

```
<?php echo $country[$customer['country_id']]['country_name']; ?>
```

Comment: Won't this method build a php array every time that will be equivalent to selecting in a mysql database?

Comment: Hum, never used memcache, I'll go have a look and see how it works, thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between having FK support and not having it is ensuring integrity. If you were to use an engine that supported FK's it wouldnt allow you to set the country without having that record's ID.

That said the number of countries is semi-static and we are only talking in the hundreds... you could potentially keep keep all these in memory and have the ID's avialable.

Alternatively you could do a select during the insert like:

`INSERT INTO sometable (col1,col2,country_id) VALUES('val1','val2', (SELECT id FROM countries WHERE iso_code = ?))`

`?` would be your ISO value.

Comment: Damn, I was hoping there was a way to avoid executing a select on each insertion, will this slow down insertions a lot?

Comment: Probably not if you have the proper indexes on your tables. I mean personally I probably wouldnt even go the route of usin MyISAM for performance reasons. The only real reason I'd ever use it is for full text search, but any more i use something external like Solr so thats a non issue as well. Exactly what is the nature of the app?

Comment: It is for a log table, so multiple inserts every second, hence the MyISAM engine for fast inserts. Then in the backend, a statistics section. No editing though, this is why I don't need InnoDB's row lock.